# Html5 audio dynamic source is null, how to detect it?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, html5-audio

I have HTML5 audio element and source of it is pointed not at mp3 file directly, but at action in controller, which returns or mp3 file (FileResult) or null. Getting result takes a while (1 min), so I have implemented spinner.
If the file exists, there is no problem, I use event "onloadeddata" of audio to stop spinner. But if there is no file a I can´t catch any event so spinner is spinning but audio becomes unavailable (grey tones).

Edited: catching 'error' event on audio element works on Firefox, not on Chrome, IE, or Edge (I need it works on Chrome and IE)

I tried these events of audio (abort, emptied, error, stalled, suspend) and nothing. I tried event of source too (onerror), but nothing.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id="audioplayer" controls controlsList="nodownload" preload="none">
  <source id="sourceId" src="<%: Url.Action("Play", "Call", new { id = calledNumber.Id }) %>" type="audio/mpeg" />
  Your browser does not support the
  <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

edited by answer of @Rory McCrossan :

```js
$('#audioplayer').on({
'play': function (e) {
    if (!$(this).data('loaded')) {
        displayBusyIndicator();
    }
},
'loadeddata': function (e) {
    if (isNaN(this.duration) || this.duration === 0) {
        hideBusyIndicator();
    } else {
        hideBusyIndicator();
        $(this).data('loaded', true)
    }
},
'error': function (e) {        
        hideBusyIndicator();       
}});
```

```
 public FileResult Play(int id)
  {
    try
      {
        // getting stream of file
        // ....
        var stream = client.OpenRead(url);

        return File(stream, "audio/mpeg");
       }
    catch(Exception e)
       {
         //logging and other actions
         Response.StatusCode = 404;
         return null;
         // I tried also return File(Stream.Null, "audio/mpeg");
       }
   }
```

For exist file, works fine. But for null result of Play action in Call controller I´m not able to catch event of null source or of unavailable audio element.

Edited: works on Firefox, not on Chrome, IE, or Edge (I need it works on Chrome and IE)

Please, help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your MVC endpoint always returns a 200 OK response, event when no file is found and you return no data. As such `error` will not fire.

To work around this you could check the `duration` property of the media that is loaded, something like this:

```js
$('#audioplayer').on({
  'play': function(e) {
    if (!$(this).data('loaded')) {
      displayBusyIndicator();
    }
  },
  'loadeddata': function(e) {
    if (isNaN(this.duration) || this.duration === 0) {
      // empty data
      // show an error message here...
    } else {
      hideBusyIndicator();
      $(this).data('loaded', true)
    }
  }
});
```

Note the use of a `data` attribute here instead of the global variable. This is better practice and will allow you to use multiple `audio` and `video` elements within a page.

Finally, I would suggest you instead change your endpoint to return a 404 NotFound HTTP status code when there is no file, and then you can simply hook to the `error` event to update the UI.

Comment: Hi,thanks, but it is not working. If I return response with status OK 200 and null as FileResult, this code doesn´t catch it (on 'loadeddata'). If I return status 404 and null, it won´t  catch on 'error'  either.  I don´t know what else to do .

Comment: Could you please add the MVC logic in the `Play` action to your question.